# How to normalise user data from varying structures in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Users in my Meteor app can create accounts 'manually' or with the accounts-facebook package.

If they create an account manually then in the database their email is stored like this:

```
emails: [address: 'hi@gmail.com', verified: false]
```

But if they use the Facebook login then its stored like this:

```
services: {
  facebook: {
    email: "james@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

I have an user account page where I need to display the users email and allow them to change it. How can I deal with the varying structure?

I made this React component to display the users email. When I just had the default Meteor user profiles it worked, but now Ive added Facebook login it errors as props.user.emails doenst exist.

```
        <div className="form-primary__row">
          <label>Email:</label>
          {props.user.emails.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <input defaultValue={item.address} key={i} name="email" />
            );
          })}
        </div>
```

This is my method for a user to update their email. It also worked when I just had Meteors accounts but won't work with Facebook.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'user.updateEmail'({ email }) {
    Meteor.users.update(
      { _id: Meteor.userId() },
      {
        $set: {
          'emails.0.address': email,
          'emails.0.verified': false,
        },
      },
    );
  },
});
```

Comment: How about storing manual emails also in a similar structure format? Eg. ```services.manual.email``` Assuming that there can only exist either manual emails OR fb emails, you can program your logic to return like either of the two, based on whichever exists. I believe this can be normalized on the client code and sent back as a standard object to the client so that the client need not bother about the structure of the object it received.

Comment: Can you normalize in a publish function? If I normalize in a client component eg my accounts page then I may need to do the same on another page, which violates the DRY principal.

Comment: Ok, I think you can make use of [```Accounts.onCreateUser()```](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-onCreateUser). When a new user is created (irrespective of manual or via fb), pull the respective email and populate the ```emails``` array. That way, you don't have to touch your publications or your client side rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use [`Accounts.onCreated()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-onCreateUser)

> The function should return the user document (either the one passed in
>   or a newly-created object) with whatever modifications are desired.
>   The returned document is inserted directly into the Meteor.users
>   collection.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    // if the account is created using the manual approach,
    // simply return the user object that will be inserted into
    // the Users collection.
    if (!user.services.facebook) {
        return user;
    }

    // if user is created using fb's API,
    // manually set the emails array, then return the user object
    // which will be inserted into the Users collection.
    user.username = user.services.facebook.name;
    user.emails = [{address: user.services.facebook.email}];

    return user;
});
```

The above ensures that the `emails` array always contains the email, whichever the login method the user chooses to use.